# AttributeError: module 'hvac' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to get all the secret from vault as key value pair but facing this issue while running the script

AttributeError: module 'hvac' has no attribute 'Client'

Please help if there is any alternative way to do this. I am new in this

```
import os
import hvac
client = hvac.Client()
client = hvac.Client(
url=os.environ['xxxxxxx],
token=os.environ['xxxxxxxxx']
)
print(client.read('secretKey'))
```

I expect to get all the secret from vault as a key value pair

Comment: Add the output from `pip freeze` to your question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "22.py", line 18, in <module>
    import hvac
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/hvac.py", line 5, in <module>
    client = hvac.Client()
AttributeError: module 'hvac' has no attribute 'Client'

Comment: Do you have a module named `hvac.py`? This will prevent loading the real module.

Comment: yes, I had module named hvac.py module. now this problem is resolved.

Comment: do you know how to get the secret from Hashicorp vault . my above code is not working

Comment: What error are you getting?